# "In the process" VS "During the process"

Tags: phrases, prepositions

Below are some sentences involved these two phrases. Could "during" and "in" be replaced by each other?

**During the process**

1. the permeability damage to coal reservoirs caused *during the
   development process* is one of the most important factors affecting productivity
2. The temporal gene expression profile *during the entire process* of apoptosis and cell cycle progression

**In the process**

1. exposure to avoided material, affective arousal, and emotional tolerance are important components *in the process* of change in therapy
2. *In the process*, each stalemated the other while demeaning itself.

Comment: I don't think so. Your first two examples use _during_ to mean _while the process is happening_. The third example refers to _components in_ the process; you could also use _components of_, but not _during_. The last example seems to use _in the process_ as a stock phrase meaning 'as an unintended part of a course of action' (I found this definition by googling 'in the process').

Answer (score 1):

"During" = concurrent with but not necessarily a component of the process

"In" = a component of the process